# Display database table columns according to the table

Tags: python, html, mysql, angularjs, django

Hi I have following code to display all the tables in my database (Python JSON formated view)

```
class DbTablesResourceView(JSONResponseMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        status = 'error'
        msg = "Success"
        from django.db import connection
        tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
        seen_models = connection.introspection.installed_models(tables)
        return self.render_json_response(dict(objects=list(tables)))
```

and I have a drop-down option to display all the tables in html as below. Used angular Js to display as a drop-down list.

```
    <div class="input-group well">
       <span class="input-group-addon addon">Table </span>
       <select type="input" class="form-control" ng-model="final_data.table"
       ng-options="t for t in table_list" required ng-cloak></select>
   </div>
```

My goal here is to display the columns of the user selected table in another drop-down option. How can I do that? Since Django tastiepie will not be a good idea to do that. Some helping hands please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `ng-change` directive in your select box, in which you can access the ng-model of select option and get the filtered columns of selected table. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: Thats a good suggestion vpsingh. But the problem am facing here how to get the specific columns from the selected table. (Its a database table)

Comment: you have to make one more server request from ng-change method in which selected table name will be the query parameter based on that table name execute your database query to return all the columns for same table.

Comment: Yes vpsingh. Do you have any idea how to make that query by mutating the existing python code?

Comment: I am not sure about python code, but if u r calling any service like `$http.get('/api/getData?table=tableName')` then your `request.form` will have all the query parameters in your python code. so `request.form` will be `{"table": "tableName"}`. hope it will help u.